# Кэширование картинки в браузере

Tags: php, html, кэширование, css

Подскажите, как лучше сделать кеширование в браузере.
Есть страница, на которой выводится картинка, одна и та жа на странице раз 50. Есть ли варианты улучшить загрузку страницы, кроме как через css?

Comment: @wwwplaton, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Картинка, которая указана 50 раз на одной странице с одним и тем же путем загрузки будет загружаться только один раз! А не 50.

Если надо все-таки кеширования картинки в браузере клиента, то этого обычно хватает `Cache-Control: private, max-age=60` более подробно советую прочесть [Кеширования статики](http://ruhighload.com/post/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+Cache-control)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать выдержку ответа здесь, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Ответы-ссылки могут стать недействительными в случае изменения страницы, на которую дана ссылка.

Answer (score 0):

Вряд ли. А чем вам css не угодил? Выводить эту картинку как background, один раз в стиль загрузится - и все, дальше будет просто подставляться. А так вы грузите одну и ту же картинку 50 раз. Кэширование поможет, только если инфа статичная, а вдруг что-то динамически обновляемое придется вставить? Тогда кэширование нельзя юзать, т.к. данные будут с кэша браться.

Comment: @Влад Дяченко, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. **Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение**.